# Is there a way to iterate and display the list of key value pairs of json using Handlebar.js

Tags: javascript, json, cordova, ember.js, handlebars.js

As Iam new to javascript, I found handleBar.js can be used to template with dynamic data.

I worked on a sample which worked fine and the json structure was simple and straight forward.

```
 (function()
  {

    var wtsource = $("#some-template").html(); 
    var wtTemplate = Handlebars.compile(wtsource); 


var data = { users: [
      {url: "index.html", name: "Home" },
      {url: "aboutus.html", name: "About Us"},
      {url: "contact.html", name: "Contact"}
    ]};

Handlebars.registerHelper('iter', function(context, options) {
var fn = options.fn, inverse = options.inverse;
var ret = "";

if(context && context.length > 0) {
for(var i=0, j=context.length; i<j; i++) {
  ret = ret + fn($.extend({}, context[i], { i: i, iPlus1: i + 1 }));
}
} else {
ret = inverse(this);
}
return ret;
});

var temp=wtTemplate(data);
$("#content").html(temp);

})();


  <script id="some-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {{#iter users}}
 <li>
    <a href="{{url}}">{{name}}</a>
 </li>
 {{/iter}}

</script>
```

How to iterate a json with the below structure ? Please do suggest the possible way for iterating and creating the template for the below json structure

```
var newData = { "NEARBY_LIST": {

        "100": {
            "RestaurantID": 100,
            "ParentRestaurantID": 0,
            "RestaurantName": "Chennai Tiffin",
            "listTime": [{
                    "startTime": "10:00",
                    "closeTime": "23:30"
                } ]
        },

        "101": {
            "RestaurantID": 101,
            "ParentRestaurantID": 0,
            "RestaurantName": "Biriyani Factory",
            "listTime": [{
                    "startTime": "11:00",
                    "closeTime": "22:00"
                }]
        }

    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but if your question is how you can use/read the data in newData, try this:

```
newData = JSON.parse(newData); //parses the JSON into a JavaScript object
```

Then access the object like so:

```
newData.NEARBY_LIST //the object containing the array
newData.NEARBY_LIST[0] //the first item (key "100")
newData.NEARBY_LIST[1] //the second item (key "101")
newData.NEARBY_LIST[0][0] //the first field of the first item (key "RestaurantID", value "100")
newData.NEARBY_LIST[0][2] //the third field of the first item (key "RestaurantName", value "Chennai Tiffin")
newData.NEARBY_LIST[0][3][0] //the first field of the fourth field of the first item (key "startTime", value "11:00")
```

I hope this was what you were looking for.

EDIT: as Siddharth points out, the above structure does assume you have arrays. If you are not using arrays you can access the properties by using their names as if they're in an associative array (e.g. `newData["NEARBY_LIST"]["100"]`. The reason I say "properties" and "as if" is because technically JavaScript doesn't support associative arrays. Because they are technically properties you may also access them like `newData.NEARBY_LIST` (but I don't recommend that in this case as a property name may not start with a number, so you would have to use a mix of the different notations).

On that note,  I would recommend using arrays because it makes so many things easier (length checks, for example), and there are practically no downsides.

EDIT2: also, I **strongly recommend** using the same camelcasing conventions throughout your code. The way you currently have it (with half your properties/variables starting with capitals (e.g. "RestaurantName", "RestaurantID") and the other half being in lowerCamelCase (e.g. "listTime", "startTime")) is just asking for people (you or colleagues) to make mistakes.

Comment: That won't work. The objects within are not in an array. You must access an object's properties by specifying the key name in the form of a string in the box brackets, not a number. What you have done would work for arrays, not objects.

Comment: ok ... How to work for an objects then ? I want to use handleBar.js for creating templates, how to go with it now for newData Json.

Comment: Check out the fiddle that I have linked to.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the properties of an object has nothing to do with Handlebars. If you dealing with JSON and you wish to access it in general bracket or dot notation, you must first parse the JSON into a JavaScript object using the `JSON.parse()` function.

After this is done, you may access the properties as follows.

```
var property = newData['NEARBY_LIST']['100'].RestaurantName; // "Chennai Tiffin"
```

Here is a fiddle to illustrate.

http://jsfiddle.net/qzm0cygu/2/

Comment: Actually my question is, in the above example they created a template for users json in the following format                           <script id="some-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {{#iter NEARBY_LIST}}
 <li>
 <a href="{{RestaurantID}}">{{RestaurantName}}</a>
 </li>
 {{/iter}}

</script>   How to create a template for the NewData Json ?

Comment: That is too broad a question to answer. But essentially, you may assign any of the object properties that you access using the notation I described in the answer above to a variable that is accessible by your Handlebars script and those should allow you to use the {{}} notation.